# Howto remove all posts that do not have a Featured images assigned to them?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins

This finds all of those:

```
$args = array(
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
       'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
       'value' => '?',
       'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
     )
  ),
);
$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How to make a mini plugin for when I activate it, it deletes all posts without a featured images assigned to them?

I trying:

```
add_action( 'init', 'process_posts' );

function process_posts() {

    $args = array(
      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
           'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
           'value' => '?',
           'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
         )
      ),
    );

    $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
     if (empty($_thumbnail_id)) {
       wp_delete_post($_POST['post_id'], true);
}
}
```

Can someone show this to me, please?. Thanks

Comment: If it's a one off piece of code that you want to execute then just attach the function to an 'init' action so that it will run when you refresh any WordPress page.

Comment: thanks by comment...I did not understand, please write a some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wordpress function `wp_delete_post()` to delete the posts. Create a for each loop getting the post id's and passing them to `wp_delete_post()`. I added this code to my functions.php file and it worked as expected. Because you have a lot of posts it may take some time to execute. It it takes too long you may have to adjust `setTimeout` in your `php.ini` file. Hope that helps!

```
$args = array(
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
       'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
       'value' => '?',
       'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
     )
  ),
);


$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        wp_delete_post($post_id);
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: hello @Derek Nolan I've tried a lot, but I'm not getting it, I have lots of thousands of posts without thumbnails to delete, you can do something more complete here. please.

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego I'll update answer to include code that I've tested and is working for me.

Comment: Helped me immensely, I would have exhaustive work without this, thank you, worked well both as a plugin, and also in template name format,
I created a folder / index.php in the theme, and I create a page in the dashboard, choosing the template name of this page, and every time I access this page the cleaning happens. thank you so much

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego Glad to be of service! I normally do this sort of thing using sql but it’s a nice little function and I’m sure I’ll find a use for it in the future. Nice little trick with index folder too! Could also leave it in functions.php and wrap the function in an if statement. If is_page($post_id)... or something like that.

Comment: Yes ... it sure is more a function to save in a special directory ... it is very useful yes, and to use in functions is yes another way :-) I have many thousands of posts to administrate, and lack filters in the plugins available. I needed that a lot. thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code of the hook you can use, you'll need to write your own loop code for deleting the posts.

```
add_action( 'init', 'process_posts' );

function process_posts() {

    $args = array(
      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
           'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
           'value' => '?',
           'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
         )
      ),
    );

    $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Delete your posts here with a loop

}
```